# Extracting values from complex and deeply nested list of dictionaires using python?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I have a complex data structure consisting of list of dictionaries and these dictionaries consists of list of dictionaries further. Now, I am trying to extract specific `key:value` pairs from internal nested dicts (from list of dictionaries). Hopefully below example shows what I am trying to achieve

```
complex_data = 
[[{'A': 'test1'}, 
  {'A': 'test2'}, 
  {'B': [{'C': {'testabc': {'A': 'xxx'}}}, 
         {'C': {'test123': {'A': 'yyy'}, 'test456': {'A': '111abc'}}}, 
         {'C': {'test123': {'A': 'yyy'}, 'test456': {'A': '111def'}}}]}],
 .
 .
 [{'A': 'test11'}, 
  {'A': 'test22'}],
 .
 .
 [{'A': 'test33'}, 
  {'A': 'test44'}, 
  {'B': []}],
 .
 [{'A': 'test3'}, 
  {'A': 'test4'}, 
  {'B': [{'C': {'testabc': {'A': '111'}}}, 
         {'C': {'test123': {'A': 'yyy'}, 'test456': {'A': '999abc'}}}, 
         {'C': {'test123': {'A': 'yyy'}, 'test456': {'A': '999def'}}}]}]]
```

Now the output should be a nested list of dictionaries like:

```
desired_output = [[{'A': 'test1'}, {'A': 'test2'}, 'test456': {'A': '111def'}],
                 .
                 .
                 [{'A': 'test3'}, {'A': 'test4'}, 'test456': {'A': '999def'}]]
```

I am doing

```
for y in complex_data:
    desired_output.append([y[2]['B'][2]['C'] for y in row] for row in y)
```

But this won't work. Varibale `y` doesn't iterate over list `B`. Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it? i am using `python3.9`

Update: In some cases, the complete list `B` could be missing or could be empty `{'B': []}`.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing or not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the main idea is to convert dict to dataframe and dataframe to append on new list by rows

Code:

Step 1:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(complex_data )
df[2] = df[2].apply(lambda x: {k:v for k , v in dict(map(dict.popitem, x['B']))['C'].items() if k=='test456'})
df
```

#Output

```
                0               1                              2
0   {'A': 'test1'}  {'A': 'test2'}  {'test456': {'A': '111def'}}
1   {'A': 'test3'}  {'A': 'test4'}  {'test456': {'A': '999def'}}
```

Step 2:

```
desired_output = df.values.tolist()
desired_output
```

#output

```
[[{'A': 'test1'}, {'A': 'test2'}, {'test456': {'A': '111def'}}],
 [{'A': 'test3'}, {'A': 'test4'}, {'test456': {'A': '999def'}}]]
```

**Update** you can avoid the None or {} value using if..else.. as below:

```
df[2].apply(lambda x: {} if len(x['B'])==0 else({} if not x['B'][-1] else ({'test456':x['B'][-1]['C']['test456']} if 'test456' in  x['B'][-1]['C'].keys() else {})))
```

Comment: Hello @R. Baraiya, thank you for the response. While executing step 1, I am getting this error `"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"`. because for some entrties B is either `[{},{},{}]` or `None`. Is there any way to skip such entries?

Comment: Hi, I still get the same error as for some entries list `B` is missing and in some cases list `B` could be only empty like `{'B': []}`. I have updated my `complex_data` input in OP for your reference.

Comment: Hi @Preeti please check update, for that you can also add if condition to first check if list empty or not

Comment: After including `df = df.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()` it worked for me. Thank you for the support!